# Node CLI Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, command-line-interface

I have a node module I am working on, and I want to write unit tests for it, however I am confused on how I would pass arguments (required for the CLI) to node through a testing suite.

Lets assume (for brevity) the module name is J, so I would call it like...

```
$ j --file test.js --file test2.js
```

how do i recreate those --file calls when I am writing my testing suite?

Answer (score 2):

You can use node's [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) module to run additional command line processes. [This link](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) can give you more info on syntax; I recommend also checking out the [promised version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise) of child-process.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

spawn('j', ['--file', 'test.js', '--file', 'test2.js'])
  .progress(function(childProcess){
    // any logic you want to do here while process is running
  })
  .then(function(result){
    // command was executed
    // write tests here
  })
  .fail(function(err){
    // maybe 1 last test to make sure there was no test
  });
```

As far as unit-testing suites, I expect anything your comfortable with would work (mocha/chai etc.)